# How do I install a specific version of Chrome in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, google-chrome

Have a Dockerfile that installs from a python image and then I need it to install a specific (not latest) version of Google Chrome.

Here's what I have:

```
FROM python:3.6

# Tools
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y vim less \
    && apt-get clean

# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeChrome/Dockerfile.txt
#============================================
# Google Chrome
#============================================
# can specify versions by CHROME_VERSION;
#  e.g. google-chrome-stable=53.0.2785.101-1
#       google-chrome-beta=53.0.2785.92-1
#       google-chrome-unstable=54.0.2840.14-1
#       latest (equivalent to google-chrome-stable)
#       google-chrome-beta  (pull latest beta)
#============================================
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
```

The Chrome installation steps were taken from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeChrome/Dockerfile.txt) (as seen in the comments) and even using the version in the example I get the error

```
E: Version '53.0.2785.101-1' for 'google-chrome-stable' was not found
```

Tried other versions from https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/ and nothing works.

Do you know of a different way to install a specific version or if I'm doing something wrong with these steps?

Comment: PS: The latest version of Chrome does get installed correctly. It's when I specify an earlier version that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took me a while to find, but you're installing from Google's repository and they only keep the latest versions of Google Chrome in their repositories. You could probably search for 3rd party repositories that have older versions of Chrome, but I personally wouldn't recommend that.

The current version is `75.0.3770.100-1` for `google-chrome-stable` at the time of this post. Will that not work for you?

Lastly, I directly copied your dockerfile and it worked for me with the latest build of google-chrome-stable installed on the image. How were you running docker?

Here was my process:

1. Copied your docker file directly into `./Dockerfile`
2. `docker build ./`
3. `docker image ls`
4. Copied my image id (90206843f24e in my case)
5. `docker run --entrypoint "/bin/bash" -it 90206843f24e`

You'll be dropped in a root shell on the docker image to "poke" around
run `google-chrome -version` to verify the above version is installed

I hope this works for you. Good luck and keep us posted!

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this @Joshua  Yeah, as mentioned in my comment, with the latest release, it works well, it's when I specify a version that it doesn't work and your answer explains why (Google only keeps the latest version in their repo, which sucks).  The reason I need an earlier version is b/c when installing the ChromeDriver, it doesn't fetch the latest version of Chromedriver (fetches version 73), so I wanted to install an earlier version of Chrome..

Comment: Oh, I understand your issue a bit better now. I'm sorry to hear that. As I've mentioned, you could possibly browse around on the Googles and try to find a 3rd party repository for an older version of Google Chrome. I'd just be through and hesitant on what you choose... This also depends how sensitive your project is. Sorry this didn't work for you and best of luck.

Comment: Expanding on docker syntax a little...
Assuming my container name is headless
=>docker exec -it headless bash                                                                                                                                                                                  
google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 81.0.4044.138

Answer (score 2):

Following up on this old thread to add that **Google does host older versions of  Google Chrome** ([you can find a list of version numbers here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable)).

Say you want Google Chrome 114.x.x.x, because your version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114:

```
ENV CHROME_VERSION=114.0.5735.198-1
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version, it works.

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use a base image with a minimal Linux distribution
FROM python:3.6

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget gnupg

# Download and install Google Chrome
ENV CHROME_VERSION=120.0.6099.129-1
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set up a user to run Chrome (optional)
RUN useradd -m -G audio,video chromeuser && \
    mkdir -p /home/chromeuser/Downloads && \
    chown -R chromeuser:chromeuser /home/chromeuser

USER chromeuser

# Command to run Chrome
CMD ["google-chrome-stable"]
```

[in docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqoYA.png)

**command**
`google-chrome --version`